# CreateCriteria and old NHibernate in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

```
var q = _session.CreateCriteria<Table>()
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Table.Status", status))
                    .SetFirstResult(pageNo * pageSize)
                    .SetMaxResults(pageSize);
                return q.List<Table>();
```

That is my code for pagination. However, it doesn't work. At the end I have problem with returning (code is placed in function). I need to convert it to type of **IList**, but how? I am forced to use old NHibernate so I cannot use Query<> and so on.

Error which is shown:

```
could not resolve property: Table of: Application.Objects.Table
```

Comment: Could you show the signature of the method that this code is located in? Also the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message it appears that there's no `Table` property inside your `Table` class. So you probably want to fix the restriction if `Status` is the property of your `Table` class:

```
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", status))
```